# Sequence Of Nested Open Interval

Tags: real-analysis

Provide an example of a sequence of nested open intervals $((an,bn))_{n=1}^{+\infty}$, $a_{n+1},b_{n+1} \subset(a_{n},b_{n})$, such that $∩_{n=1}^{\infty} (a_{n},b_{n}) = \emptyset$

Solution Attempt:

$[n,\infty)$

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  Have a look at the way your math notation currently appears.  I think there are at least a couple of ways it probably could be improved.  Note that curly braces can be used in math notation but have to be "escaped" because they have meaning in $\LaTeX$ otherwise.  E.g. use `\{(a_n,b_n)\}` to get $\{(a_n,b_n)\}$.

Comment: Do you want $(a_{n+1},b_{n+1}) \subset (a_n,b_n)$, or do you want $a_{n+1},b_{n+1}\in (a_n,b_n)$? Because for the former, the answer given by DeepSea works. For the latter, something like $$a_n=-\dfrac{1}{n}, b_n=\dfrac{1}{n}, \forall n\ge 1$$ would work (similar to DeepSea's approach, but making sure each interval is getting smaller from both ends). Also, the symbol $\subset$ could mean $\subseteq$ (used frequently in topology). Do you want to restrict to proper subsets? Because if you don't care if it is proper, then $a_n=b_n=1$ would work (as every interval is the empty set).

Comment: @InterstellarProbe I believe that in your example we have $$\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \left(-\frac1n, \frac1n\right) = \{0\}$$

Comment: @mechanodroid, you are correct. I think if $a_{n+1},b_{n+1}\in (a_n,b_n)$, then it may not be possible to generate such a sequence of open intervals.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe Yes, in that case we also have $[a_{n+1}, b_{n+1}] \subseteq [a_n, b_n], \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$ so by the Cantor intersection theorem $\exists x \in \bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}} [a_n, b_n]$. But it cannot be $x = a_n$ or $x= b_n$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ because then it would be $x \notin [a_{n+1}, b_{n+1}]$. Therefore $x \in \bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}} (a_n, b_n)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $a_n = 0, b_n = \dfrac{1}{n}, \forall n \ge 1$

Comment: Thanks. Can you please provide  some explanations.

Comment: @David suppose $$c \in \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \left(0,\dfrac{1}{n}\right)$$ Obviously, $0<c<1$, since $c \in \left(0,\dfrac{1}{1}\right)$. But then $N = \left\lceil \dfrac{1}{c} \right\rceil+1$ satisfies the property that $0<\dfrac{1}{N}<c$, so $c\notin \left(0,\dfrac{1}{n}\right)$ for any $n\ge N$, contradicting the assumption that it was in the intersection to begin with.

Comment: Doesn't this imply that 0 (a number very close to 0 at least because it is an open interval) is in the intersection? 0 is in every interval within the sequence.

Answer (score -1):

$$b_n=1$$

$$a_n=1-\frac 2n$$

$\forall \epsilon<1$, for $n$ great enough,

$$1-\frac 2n>\epsilon.$$

Comment: These are not nested. $\left(\dfrac{1}{2},\dfrac{2}{2}\right)$ is not a subset of $\left(\dfrac{1}{1}, \dfrac{2}{1}\right)$.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe Sorry i just edit an other one.

Comment: That works, but how is that different from DeepSea's solution?